# Unable to cover Apex code

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I have tried to cover below class but unable to cover even single % . Unable to figure out where/what I missed, Please anyone help me

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class customSearchController {
    public static list<ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c> getContactList(string searchKey,string productType) {
        string sTempSearchKey = '%' + searchKey + '%';
        //string sTempSearchKey = '%' + searchKey;
        // create Product list to store search result 
        list<ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c> lstProduct = new list<ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c>();
        // query Product records
        for(ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c oCon : [Select id,Name,Product_Number__c,ProductType__c,Parent_Name__c From ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c WHERE  Product_Number__c LIKE : sTempSearchKey and ProductType__c=:productType limit 10]){
            lstProduct.add(oCon);
        }
        return lstProduct;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class customSearchController_Test {
    
    static testMethod void getContactListMethod() {
        try{  
            
        list<Account> acclist=new list<Account>();
        Account acc=new Account();
        acc.name='Hasbro Dev Stg Res 2';
        acc.ICIX_V1__Status__c='Active';
        acc.ICIX_V1__ICIX_ID__c='304078';
        //acc.ICIX_V1__Internal__c=true;
        acclist.add(acc);
        insert acclist;
            
        string searchKey;
        string productType;
        
        list<ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c> lstProduct = new list<ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c>();
        string sTempSearchKey = '%' + searchKey + '%';
      
        ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c product1=Hasbro_TestDataFactory.createProduct()[0];
        product1.Product_Number__c='C6119AV10';
        product1.ProductType__c='ASSORTMENT'; 
        lstProduct.add(product1);
        
        ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c product2=Hasbro_TestDataFactory.NewProduct();
        product2.Product_Number__c='C6119AV10';
        product2.ProductType__c='ASSORTMENT';
        lstProduct.add(product2);
        
        insert lstProduct;
       
        customSearchController.getContactList('product2.Product_Number__c','product2.ProductType__c');
    }
    
    catch(Exception e){
        
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I gone through this but not helping in my case

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of major issues here that will cause your test class not to work, to produce false positives, or to otherwise misbehave.

- You need to remove that empty exception handler. You should *never* do this in a test class, as it can produce false positives. If you code is going to throw an exception **you need to know about that in a test class**.
- You have written no assertions, so you have no idea if your code works or not.
- Your code is doing work that is unneeded. You can directly return a SOQL query result; there no need (and it is wasteful) to construct another list.
- The parameters you are passing in `customSearchController.getContactList('product2.Product_Number__c','product2.ProductType__c')` make no sense for what this class does, and as a result, your query returns nothing. You need to shape the parameters to match the test data you have inserted.